# Missing Mass Transit AddMassTransitTestHarness method

Tags: c#, masstransit

MT docs (here: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html) say that for testing a consumer using a container based configuration, we should do something like this:

```
await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    })
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);
```

I have MassTransit 7.3.1 installed, but the sample code method `AddMassTransitTestHarness` is nowhere to be found. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `AddMassTransitTestHarness` is implemented in `MassTransit` as the extension method for `IServiceCollection` interface in `DependencyInjectionTestingExtensions` class, which was introduced in version `8.0.0`

What you are missing is 8 months of the package updates. Try upgrading MassTransit to the newest version.

Comment: Working for a top secret company mate, new MT version has not yet been approved by our security team XD But yeah, I just noticed that, I'll push them to work faster :)